# Constructor for Vector Linked List Struccture

Tags: java, generics, vector, linked-list, hashmap

I am attempting to make a data structure, which is essentially a hash table, that is composed of linked lists within a vector. Where each node of the linked list holds the link, the element, E and the key, K. In each index of the vector, there should be a linked list.

I am attempting to create the constructor but I am having some trouble doing so as I don't know how to initialize my object to contain a linked list inside of each vector index. The error I am receiving is as follows:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
>   List cannot be resolved to a variable
>   K cannot be resolved to a variable
>    E cannot be resolved to a variable
>     list cannot be resolved to a variable
>      Syntax error on token "=", <= expected
>     Incorrect number of arguments for type LinkedList; it cannot be  >parameterized with arguments K, E

I am looking for the table to be made holding a Linked List in each index by use of the constructor.

Can anyone help or push me in the right direction with this one? So far this is what I have:

```
import java.util.*;

public class NewTable <K, E> {

private Vector <LinkedList<HashPair <K,E>>> table;

public NewTable(int capacity){
    if (capacity <= 0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Capacity is negative.");
    }
    else{


        table = new Vector<LinkedList<HashPair<K, E>>>(capacity);

        for (int i=0;i<table.capacity();i++){
            table.set(i, List<K, E> list = new LinkedList<K, E>());
        }
    }   
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    NewTable<String, String> table = new NewTable<String, String>(5);

    table.put("Good", "Food");
}

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly.  See also: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Joe C I thank you for the welcome! I have just made some edits removing all the unnecessary code and only those pertaining to the problem.

Comment: Also, Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: @Joe C, I have just added these as well, I thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
table.set(i, List<K, E> list = new LinkedList<K, E>());
```

This is not valid Java.  You simply cannot declare a new variable in the middle of a method call.

You honestly don't need a variable called `list` here, so you can simply omit it, like so:

```
table.add(new LinkedList<HashPair<K, E>>());
```

(Note: I've also changed `set` to `add`, as `set` assumes that something already exists at the specified index.)

EDIT: I didn't realise that you had two type parameters on your `LinkedList`.  Updated that part of my answer as well.

Comment: This exact solution did not work but you definitely led me to the solution. The <K,E> were invalid parameters for the Linked list. So Instead what I did was the following:    table.add(new LinkedList<HashPair<K, E>>());

Comment: Yeah, I missed that as well.  Don't forget to upvote and accept this answer if you found it helpful.